# How do I tune a slow view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app view that is too slow.

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/calendar" host=xxxx.ndeavor3.com request_id=8f38737e-f193-4949-be83-5295dd9c18dd fwd="198.50.4.5" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Calendar view contains this query :

```
<%= collection_select :workorder, :id, Workorder.wonotclosed.where("employee_id = ?", current_user.employee.id), :id, :wonum_desc, :include_blank => 'None' %>
```

Would it help if I index workorders on employee_id?

wonotclosed is comparing `wostatus_id` - should I index that?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd probably move the gathering of the work orders into a controller and out of your view code.

Also, I think you're right that an index on `employee_id` could help you here.